# Java Swing Absolute Coordinates

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have a program which jpanels on a jframe using setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));  I would like to use these jpanels as the background and have a separate jpanel on top.  How would I implement this so that the jpanel on top could be moved and placed using setLocation, setBounds, or the like?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: A little more context to you problem might help.  If you're writing a game, then using components as entities is a bad idea, as the component based API has a lot of requirements on the layout manager API

Comment: Right now I have a player class, which extends an Entity class, which extends JComponent.  I realized that the component api depends heavily on the layout managers, but i wasn't sure what else I could use.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Set the panels parents layout manager to null.

Once this has been done you can place it's children wherever you want with set bounds .

Comment: My problem is that both the Jpanel that i want to use setBounds on and the jpanels using FlowLayout have the same parent, the main JFrame.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: The traditional way of doing that would be to write your own layout manager , although i am unsure if that is now frowned upon.

Comment: *"The traditional way of doing that would be to write your own layout manager.."*  That would make a better answer than the current answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson my initial reading of the question was that he was struggling with setting bounds of his panels directly ( so my answer was based on the simplest method possible of removing a items from a layout manager's grip ) Writing a layout manager is a slightly more involved undertaking then simple absolute placement, so I am not sure if its worth sending someone on a 2 hour tangent unless they absolutely have to. Especially because I am not 100% sure that custom layout managers are still considered a best practice.

Comment: *"..the simplest method possible of removing a items from.."* ..any logic whatsoever.  Which will lead to 4 more questions as to how to fix the problems that causes.  If there ***is*** a logic to the layout, it should be encapsulated in a custom layout manager.